# Load a web page to send data

Tags: c#

Assume that I have a php script which saves get queries on `info` parameter. I have it as a string variable:

```
string url = "http://example.com/write.php?info="
```

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
string info = "asd";
```

So I want to load the web page without showing to user. The url will be `url`+`info`

How can i do that?

Comment: "Load the web page" could be interpreted in any number of ways. What do you mean exactly? What is the ultimate goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
var fullUrl = url + info;
var conent = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(fullUrl);
```